# Database project build fails due to syntax errors in non-existent files

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to build a database project where I was trying to create a system-versioned table within my Visual Studio 2017 solution, but I am suddenly getting an error:

> SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near ]

Normally, that would be a simple fix....except the file it refers to doesn't exist! When I double-click the error within the Error List, I get:

> Cannot find file 'MSSQL::dbo.TestHISTORY'

The table it refers to is one that I had named as part of the SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (minus the MSSQL:: prefix) command for another table I created. I have restarted Visual Studio, reverted all the changes I made to the database project, restarted my PC, performed a Clean operation against the project but all to no avail!

Has anyone else come up against this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by deleting the .jfm and .dbmdl files from the root directory for the database project. After restarting Visual Studio the database project would finally build!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well.  Odd that the 'Clean' operation doesn't clean up those files.  I see they are ignored by the recommended `.gitignore`, so deleting the directory and re-cloning should also work.